# Reset Digital Wellbeing timers

Tags: digital-wellbeing

Everyday I set digital wellbeing timers to zero(0) and increase then by 5 minutes everytime I need access to an app, this is how I'm coping with my phone addiction.

Sometimes if I extend an app timer to 30mins someday it remains the same and I will use the app for 30mins everyday until I realise and put it to 0-5mins again.

So, is there a way to reset these timers everyday to zero ?